# How to get Sell/Buy Volume for each candle in pine script?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I know that we can get the volume of each candle with https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_volume

I am wondering if there is a way to get the sell/buy volume for each candle?

Answer (score 0):

Only request.quandl

You can look this data up on Quandl (Nasdaq). Maybe they are there and you can import them. In the standard functionality of the pine script - did not meet such a possibility